# Java JPA Left Join that are not separated by a comma

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Error in the translation of the MYSQL structure in the JPA structure

I have 100% worked mysql query:

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM list_orders LEFT JOIN orders_translate where list_orders._id=orders_translate._order_id

query JPA
String query = "SELECT t1 FROM ListOrders t1  LEFT  JOIN  t1.speakers e  WHERE e._id = t1._id";

```
public class OrdersTranslate implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "_id")
private Long id;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "_english_name")
private String englishName;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "_arabic_name")
private String arabicName;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "_russian_name")
private String russianName;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "_french_name")
private String frenchName;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "_order_id")
private int order_id;
```

}

public class ListOrders implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "_id")
@SerializedName("_id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "_number_id")
@SerializedName("_number_id")
private int numberId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "name")
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<OrdersTranslate> speakers;
```

}

I get next error:

[53, 54] The FROM clause has 'ListOrders t1 LEFT JOINN t1.oerders' and 'e ' that are not separated by a comma.
[42, 53] The identification variable 't1.oerders' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.
[56, 56] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.

Whats wrong in JPA query? MySQL query works correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first - you don't have OneToOne join if you have array of OrdersTranslate in ListOrders table. This is OneToMany join.

Please try in your ListOrders class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="listOrders")
private List<OrdersTranslate> speakers;
```

In your OrdersTranslate class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "_order_id")
private ListOrders listOrders;
```

And then your JPA Query will look:

```
SELECT t1 FROM ListOrders t1 LEFT JOIN t1.speakers e
```